# How do you convert the ev3p program files and assets back into an ev3 project file?

Tags: ev3

I edited the ev3p file, and I want to see the changes by opening it in the ev3 IDE. How do I convert all of the files back into an ev3 project file?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. To anyone who wants to know, the reason why the ev3 IDE wouldn't work is because I made a zip file with the folder with the all of the items instead of compressing the items themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The `.ev3` is simply a zip file. So you can use just zip everything up in a `.zip` file and then rename the file extension from `.zip` to `.ev3`.

Comment: I've tried this, but whenever I try to open the .ev3 file again in the IDE it opens a blank page and then closes out of it immediately.

Comment: Perhaps the change you made in the .ev3p file is causing the unexpected behavior?

Comment: I probably should've described my situation better. I am on a mac btw. These are the exact steps I took: 1. Create a normal ev3 project in the IDE. 2. Duplicate this and unzip the duplicate using The Unarchiver. 3. Compress this duplicate folder using mac's built in compression. 4. Rename the extension to .ev3. I haven't made any changes to the contents of the project.

Comment: Should i try doing this on a windows pc instead?